# OpenShift rhc app create (Errno::EMSGSIZE)

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I want to create WebSocket java application using this tutorial: https://blog.openshift.com/deploy-websocket-web-applications-with-jboss-wildfly/ . I created account, installed ruby, git, rhc, logged in successfully, created key, domain. I should create app then. `rhc app create wildfly diy` command causes error and this console output:

```
Using diy-0.1 (Do-It-Yourself 0.1) for 'diy'
Application Options
-------------------
Domain:     weedteam
Cartridges: diy-0.1
Gear Size:  default
Scaling:    no

Creating application 'wildfly' ... done

  Disclaimer: This is an experimental cartridge that provides a way to try unsupported languages, frameworks, and middleware on OpenShift.

    Waiting for your DNS name to be available ... D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb
:759:in `recvfrom': Komunikat wys│any na gniazdo datagramu by│ wiŕkszy ni┐ wewnŕ
trzny bufor lub przekracza│ inny sieciowy limit albo bufor u┐ywany do odbierania
 datagramˇw by│ mniejszy ni┐ sam datagram. - recvfrom(2) (Errno::EMSGSIZE)
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:759:in `recv_reply'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:690:in `request'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:528:in `block in fetch_resource'

        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1096:in `block (3 levels) in res
olv'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1094:in `each'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1094:in `block (2 levels) in res
olv'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1093:in `each'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1093:in `block in resolv'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1091:in `each'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:1091:in `resolv'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:519:in `fetch_resource'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:509:in `each_resource'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:500:in `getresources'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/helpers.rb:43
4:in `host_exists?'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/commands/app.
rb:675:in `block in dns_propagated?'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/commands/app.
rb:674:in `upto'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/commands/app.
rb:674:in `dns_propagated?'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/commands/app.
rb:201:in `block in create'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/highline_exte
nsions.rb:190:in `call'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/highline_exte
nsions.rb:190:in `section'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/highline_exte
nsions.rb:204:in `paragraph'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/helpers.rb:33
7:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Helpers>'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/commands/app.
rb:199:in `create'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:2
94:in `execute'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:2
85:in `block (3 levels) in to_commander'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/co
mmand.rb:180:in `call'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/co
mmand.rb:180:in `call'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/co
mmand.rb:155:in `run'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/ru
nner.rb:419:in `run_active_command'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/command_runne
r.rb:72:in `run!'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/de
legates.rb:8:in `run!'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in
`start'
        from D:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (
required)>'
        from D:/Ruby22/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from D:/Ruby22/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

When I check on the website, the app is created and running, but I can't proceed to the next step of this tutorial

```
$ cd wildfly
$ rhc app stop --app wildfly
$ git rm diy/index.html
$ git rm diy/testrubyserver.rb
```

`cd wildfly` is not working, `rhc app stop --app wildfly` stops app (as it should), and another 2 commands can't find repo. I think it's because create app command should do something more, but it was interrupted by this error. Am I wrong? What can I do to stop this error from happening?

Comment: I see you are running `rhc` with Ruby version 2.2.0 on a Windows machine. That is a notoriously buggy/broken combination. Try switching to Ruby 1.9.3 and reinstalling rhc.

Comment: Thx for reply. I uninstalled gems, uninstalled ruby 2.2.0, installed ruby 1.9.3, installed rhc and the same error occured.

Comment: try to directly `git clone` to fix your local git before you proceed.

Comment: Can you translate that error into english? That might help us help you.

Comment: @VilibaldW. W. I used `rhc git-clone -a app_name` and it was cloned successfully. However, after using all the commands from this section of this tutorial I got 503 error.

Comment: @corey112358 "Message sent to datagram socket was bigger than internal buffer or exceeded another network limit or buffer used for receiving datagrams was smaller than the datagram itself."

Comment: Are you connecting through a proxy or some type of corporate firewall?

Comment: @corey112358 i tried internet connection in another place and it worked, so it looks like there might be some sort of firewall (it was a hotel network). Using another internet connection solved this problem, however after using all commands from this section of this guide (with success) I still get 503 error at the end when I try to view the site.

Comment: I usually encounter port 22 (ssh) being blocked at hotels also.  You should check your log files and see what they say about your issue.